# Value of security through amiguity?

Tags: security-definition, semantic-security

Let's say that you have a symmetric cipher which takes in an 8 bit plain text value and a key, and generates cipher text which can be decoded using the key to get the original plain text value.

Since this is just an 8 bit plain text value, versus say some text document in english (or other source material where the format is known), if the cipher is based on common modern day crypto techniques, what avenues would likely be available to an attacker to know what the plain text value (or key) was?

As an extension to the above, let's say that the cipher text of that 8 bit plain text value was encrypted such that when using key $k_0$ the cipher text would decrypt to the value $0$, using key $k_1$ the cipher text would decrypt to the value $1$ and so on up to key $k_{255}$ which would cause the cipher text to be decoded to the value $255$.  Since the ACTUAL meaning of the cipher text was completely ambiguous, would this thwart any abilities to analyze what key and plain text value were actually used?

I know that creating such a cipher text would be more time consuming and probably result in a larger cipher text as well as larger key(s).  It may also not seem useful to completely ambiguously encode data this way, but I'm curious if it removes any attack surfaces.  It also seems like it could be useful to semi-ambiguate cipher text for a smaller set than "all possible inputs" to perhaps lessen the above attack surface by having multiple answers to a correct decoding.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the revelation of a (one correct, though by itself meaningless according to you) sequence of the "plain text values" a critical issue of security? If yes, the adversary needs only to brute-force all 256 keys (the key space is quite tiny) IMHO.

Comment: I don't think so,  but I get your meaning.  My thinking is that even though there are only 256 keys, in the standard case there is only 1 key, so it'd be 256 times as strong.